# Why date set as variable is changing by jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery-ui for making a vaccine schedule on user input.

Below is the `Schedule` of the vaccine:

[image: Vaccine Schedule]

here, d=day, m=month, y=year.

Below is the `Schedule Form` from where the date of above schedule can be made:
[image: Schedule Form]

You can see, if a user set `01/09/2015` as `Date of Birth`, then `1 day after Birth` is `02/09/2015` for `Anti Rabies Vaccine - 1st Dose`

On the other hand, for the same `Date of Birth` , 10 year after birth should be `01/09/2015` which is `Cervical Cancer - 1st Dose`. But my schedule form is giving 1st Dose as `02/09/2015`

This is also true for `Hepatitis-A (Adult) - 1st Dose`.

So, instead calculating from `Date of Birth`, `1st Dose of Cervical Cancer` is calculating from `1st Dose of Anti Rabies Vaccine` and `1st Dose of Hepatitis-A (Adult)` Vaccine is calculating from `1st Dose of Cervical Cancer` Vaccine instead calculating from Date of Birth.

This is happening because in my jQuery code, I declared selected date of birth as a variable `var date2`. This `date2` is changing at the later part of code while I am using an equation `var date1=date2` which should not be. I want to tell the jQuery engine that let date1 is date2, but it is altering the value of date2 itself. If this can be fixed, i.e value of date2 can be kept constant, then the jQuery code will work as I expected. But I can't figure it out why value of date2 is changing to value of date1 by the equation `var date1=date2`.

Instead of mentioning the full jQuery code here, I am giving a jsfiddle in which all HTML, CSS as well as the jQuery code are shown.

Please follow this link for testing purpose:

http://jsfiddle.net/infomamun/82c7s3te/

Comment: If the same schedule can make by modifying my code, such as attaching `on change` event instead `on close` event of input fields, your answer will be accepted.

Comment: "Instead of mentioning the full jQuery code here" - please copy the critical part of your code back here. Questions that simply link to off-site code are regarded as off-topic, based on how often we have to repair/delete them when links break.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the date based on the previous ones. See your last functional line:

```
$(this).datepicker('setDate', date1);
```

After the first row, `date1` is 1 day after the birthday. That throws off the calculations for the rest of the chart.

To fix it, i would recommend storing the date using jQuery's `.data()` method instead, and resetting it to the birthday at the end of each row.

But is it really a problem? After all, who wants to go get those shots on their birthday? :)

Comment: It will be my pleasure if you modify my jsfiddle and give the modified version of that jsfiddle. Yes it is really a problem. The 1st dose of vaccine is not taking at date of birth, it is day after day of birth or even 10 years of date of birth (in case of cervical cancer vaccine).  1st dose of Anti Rabbies Vaccine is just a sample code for demonstration......lol

Comment: Scimonster, I am not using `date1` as fixed date, I am using `date2` as fixed/constant date and by last functional line I am setting `date1`, not the `date2`. So `date2` should remain unchanged through out the code.